# How to prove that, the set of all matrices $M_n{\mathbb R}$ with distinct eigen values is dense in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to prove that the set of all matrices $M_n{\mathbb R}$  with distinct eigen values is dense in $\mathbb R^n$?

Is there any geometric interpretations behind this.. if it is so, then tell me how to construct a dense subset of $\mathbb R^n$ geometrically.

Comment: A crude outline: The set of matrices such that their characteristic polynomial has multiple zeros is Zariski closed. The set $U$ of diagonalizable matrices contains the complement of that set. Because $M_n(\Bbb{R})$ is irreducible, any Zariski open set is dense w.r.t. both Zariski topology and the usual topology. Not sure this is very useful :-/

Comment: Hint: the set of the all points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in wich all entries are distincts are dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$? as opposed to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: yes@Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 6):

It suffices to note that for any $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, we may construct a sequence $A_m \to A$ where each $A_m$ has distinct eigenvalues.

We begin by noting that $A$ is block upper-triangularizable, so that $A = STS^{-1}$, with
$$
T = \pmatrix{T_1&&* \\&\ddots\\&&T_k}
$$
Where $T_i$ is either an element of $\Bbb R$ or a block of the form 
$$
T_i = \pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}
$$
with $a,b \in \Bbb R$.  Now define
$$
T^{(m)} = \pmatrix{\left(1 - \frac 1m\right) T_1&&* \\&\ddots\\&& \left( 1 - \frac km\right) T_k}
$$
We note that $T^{(m)}$ has distinct eigenvalues for all but finitely many $m$ (i.e. for all $m$ bigger than some $M \in \Bbb N$).  Now, define the sequence by $A_m = ST^{(m)}S^{-1}$.

Comment: i am sorry .. i could not under stand.. should i need any pre requisite for this...@omnomnomnom

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you didn't understand?  One way to view this is to say that $STS^{-1}$ is the [real Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of a matrix $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: May I ask why in the last sentence of your proof " for all but finitely many $m$" $T^{m}$ has distinct eigenvalues? It seems to me for all $m \ge 2$, the eigenvalues are different.

Comment: @iris2017 we might end up with a repeated eigenvalue by coincidence for some values $m \geq 2$.  However, this can happen at most finitely many times.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Could you give an example? I could not see the case. Thanks.

Comment: @iris2017 with 
$$
T = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&4}
$$
we find that $T^{(5)}$ has repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I see. Thanks. But then intuitively I can see this can happen only finitely many times. Is there a formal argument?

Comment: For each pair $T_p,T_q$, there is at most one value of $m$ such that 
$$
(1 - \frac pm)T_p = (1 - \frac qm)T_q
$$
and there are only finitely many pairs

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks so much for answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a map $f$ which takes an appropriately sized set of eigenvalues paired with their respective eigenvectors and outputs the (unique) matrix having those eigenvalues and eigenvectors. This function is bijective and continuous almost everywhere (since each entry of the outputed matrix would be a rational function of the input) and, clearly, in the input domain the set of sets of eigenvalues with no repeats would be dense, and by continuity, the image of this set would be dense too.