# Eigen values of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A be a $n\times n$ complex matrix. I have to determine eigenvalues of the linear operator $T$ on $n\times n$ matrices such that $T(B)=AB-BA$ in terms of eigenvalues of $A$.

A hint will be enough.

Comment: Pretend first that $B$ is diagonalizable, in which case you can WLOG assume that $B$ is diagonal. In the general case, recall that the diagonalizable matrices are dense (in the geometric or the Zariski topology) in all matrices, and that what you are proving is a polynomial identity (the last part is tricky).

Comment: Sorry but I don't know zariski topology etc. I'm asking you a general question, Suppose we have to prove some arguement for a general matrix, when can we assume that it holds for a diagonizable matrix so holds in general. @darij grinberg

Answer (score 0):

First, take $A$ to be diagonal with diagonal entries $\lambda_i$.  We note that
$$
AB - BA = \lambda B \iff\\
\forall i,j: (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)b_{ij} = \lambda b_{ij} \iff\\
\forall i,j: (\lambda_i - \lambda_j - \lambda)b_{ij} = 0
$$
So, for every pair $i,j$: $\lambda = \lambda_i - \lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue where the eigenvector is given by the matrix $(b_{pq})$ such that
$$
b_{pq} = 
\begin{cases}
1 & p = i,q = j\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, $0$ is always an eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $n$.

Now, we need to extend this to all diagonalizable matrices, then to all matrices.

---

**Hint:** given a matrix $A$, let $T_A(B)$ denote the map you describe.  Show that if $A = SDS^{-1}$, then
$$
T_A(B) = S[T_D(S^{-1}BS)]S^{-1}
$$

Comment: Please reply to my comment above.

Comment: Not all arguments, but certain arguments can be extended in this way. We don't need all that about Zariski density. What you need to do consists of two steps: first, use $A = SDS^{-1}$ to prove that if $A$ is diagonalizable, then the same applies. From there, use the fact that *every matrix is the limit of a sequence of diagonalizable matrices*.

Comment: For an example of such a sequence, look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045187/81360).